# Difference between ATTRS and ATTR in udev rules?

Tags: linux, udev

What's the difference between ATTRS and ATTR in udev rules? Aren't both attributes? Why the distinction?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The singular form of `udev` criteria (`KERNEL`, `SUBSYSTEM`, `DRIVER`, `ATTR`) only match the device being added, whereas the plural forms (including `ATTRS`) match the device being added or any of its parent devices.

See the [Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) guide for details.